# SQL Server: table locked by SELECT statement?

Tags: sql-server, database, locking

In the database behind our application we have a decent sized table (36 columns, 3 and a half million rows) that is causing us some performance headaches.

This is the weight of the table (over 6 gigs):

```
tablename   row_count   reserved    data       index_size   unused  schemaname
tab           3535587   6427640 KB  1797296 KB  4629504 KB  840 KB  dbo
```

Recently we find out that sometimes, probably when the database and the table is under heavy concurrent use, the entire table looks locked.

Running a query to list the transaction we can find plenty of `SELECT` queries all blocked waiting for an `UPDATE` statement on this table.

The thing that looks strange to us is that the `UPDATE` statement is also blocked by another `SELECT` statement on the very same table. The wait type of this blocking `SELECT` usually is `PAGELATCH SH`.

Is this some king of memory subsystem problem? We have to rethink the indexing of our table?

If we kill the latching select transaction the other transactions start getting executed.

There are a LOT of queries that our systems throws on this table, that use several of the columns of the table using joins, exists, etc..sometimes those queries are really big.

N.B. We use Hibernate as our ORM.

Something that also looks strange to me (but maybe it's normal) is that the amount of ram memory consumed by our db is not very high (the server is not a db only instance, it runs also a couple of Tomcat instances for the app itself): it rarely goes over 500 Mb but usually stays around 300..

EDIT: This is the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno](
    [id] [varchar](36) NOT NULL,
    [dt_ordine_giorno] [date] NULL,
    [n_ore] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [hh_inizio] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [hh_fine] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [overload] [int] NULL,
    [nota] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [fk_e0_turno] [varchar](36) NULL,
    [fk_e2_per_dipendente] [varchar](36) NULL,
    [fk_e1_tur_orario_servizio] [varchar](36) NULL,
    [fk_e0_gg_operativo] [varchar](36) NULL,
    [fk_e0_gg_paghe] [varchar](36) NULL,
    [fk_parent_ordine_giorno] [varchar](36) NULL,
    [fk_e0_tipo_rischio] [varchar](36) NULL,
    [fk_e0_utente_inserimento] [varchar](36) NULL,
    [fk_e0_utente_modifica] [varchar](36) NULL,
    [dt_modifica] [datetime2](0) NULL,
    [dt_inserimento] [datetime2](0) NULL,
    [fk_e0_prof_nodo] [varchar](36) NULL,
    [riga] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [dt_paghe] [date] NULL,
    [fl_bloccato] [bigint] NULL,
    [fl_temporaneo] [smallint] NULL,
    [tipo_riga] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [hh_ordinarie] [float] NULL,
    [tipo_modifica] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [fk_e1_tur_servizio] [varchar](36) NULL,
    [codice_importazione] [varchar](45) NULL,
    [fk_e1_tur_testata] [varchar](36) NULL,
    [fl_annullato] [smallint] NULL,
    [fl_compensativo] [smallint] NULL,
    [descrizione] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [fl_recupero] [tinyint] NULL,
    [fk_e0_segmento_dip] [varchar](36) NULL,
    [fl_confermato] [tinyint] NULL,
    [fk_e1_tur_pian_reperibilita] [varchar](36) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_id] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_1] FOREIGN KEY([fk_e0_utente_inserimento])
REFERENCES [dbo].[users] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] CHECK CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_1]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_10] FOREIGN KEY([fk_e0_gg_paghe])
REFERENCES [dbo].[e0_conf_gg_paghe] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] CHECK CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_10]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_11] FOREIGN KEY([fk_e1_tur_servizio])
REFERENCES [dbo].[e1_tur_servizi] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] CHECK CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_11]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_12] FOREIGN KEY([fk_e1_tur_testata])
REFERENCES [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno_testata] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] CHECK CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_12]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_2] FOREIGN KEY([fk_e0_utente_modifica])
REFERENCES [dbo].[users] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] CHECK CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_2]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_3] FOREIGN KEY([fk_e0_prof_nodo])
REFERENCES [dbo].[e0_prof_nodi] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] CHECK CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_3]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_4] FOREIGN KEY([fk_e0_turno])
REFERENCES [dbo].[e0_conf_turni] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] CHECK CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_4]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_5] FOREIGN KEY([fk_e2_per_dipendente])
REFERENCES [dbo].[e2_per_dipendenti] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] CHECK CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_5]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_6] FOREIGN KEY([fk_e1_tur_orario_servizio])
REFERENCES [dbo].[e1_tur_orari_servizi] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] CHECK CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_6]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_7] FOREIGN KEY([fk_e0_gg_operativo])
REFERENCES [dbo].[e0_conf_gg_operativi] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] CHECK CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_7]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_8] FOREIGN KEY([fk_parent_ordine_giorno])
REFERENCES [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] CHECK CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_8]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_9] FOREIGN KEY([fk_e0_tipo_rischio])
REFERENCES [dbo].[e0_decod_tipi_rischi] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] CHECK CONSTRAINT [e1_tur_ordini_giorno$FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_9]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_e0_prof_nodi] FOREIGN KEY([fk_e0_segmento_dip])
REFERENCES [dbo].[e0_prof_nodi] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_e0_prof_nodi]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_e1_tur_pian_reperibilita] FOREIGN KEY([fk_e1_tur_pian_reperibilita])
REFERENCES [dbo].[e1_tur_pian_reperibilita] ([id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_e1_tur_pian_reperibilita]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_ordin__id__5E7FE7D2]  DEFAULT (N'0') FOR [id]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__dt_or__5F740C0B]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [dt_ordine_giorno]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__n_ore__60683044]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [n_ore]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__hh_in__615C547D]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [hh_inizio]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__hh_fi__625078B6]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [hh_fine]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__overl__63449CEF]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [overload]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_ord__nota__6438C128]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [nota]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__fk_e0__652CE561]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [fk_e0_turno]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__fk_e2__6621099A]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [fk_e2_per_dipendente]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__fk_e1__67152DD3]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [fk_e1_tur_orario_servizio]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__fk_e0__68FD7645]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [fk_e0_gg_operativo]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__fk_e0__69F19A7E]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [fk_e0_gg_paghe]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__fk_pa__6AE5BEB7]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [fk_parent_ordine_giorno]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__fk_e0__6BD9E2F0]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [fk_e0_tipo_rischio]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__fk_e0__6CCE0729]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [fk_e0_utente_inserimento]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__fk_e0__6DC22B62]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [fk_e0_utente_modifica]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__dt_mo__6EB64F9B]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [dt_modifica]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__dt_in__6FAA73D4]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [dt_inserimento]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__fk_e0__709E980D]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [fk_e0_prof_nodo]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_ord__riga__7192BC46]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [riga]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__dt_pa__7286E07F]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [dt_paghe]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__fl_bl__737B04B8]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [fl_bloccato]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__fl_te__746F28F1]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [fl_temporaneo]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__tipo___75634D2A]  DEFAULT (N'N') FOR [tipo_riga]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__hh_or__76577163]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [hh_ordinarie]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__tipo___774B959C]  DEFAULT (N'N') FOR [tipo_modifica]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__fk_e1__783FB9D5]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [fk_e1_tur_servizio]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__codic__7933DE0E]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [codice_importazione]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__fk_e1__7A280247]  DEFAULT (NULL) FOR [fk_e1_tur_testata]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__fl_an__7B1C2680]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [fl_annullato]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__e1_tur_or__fl_co__7C104AB9]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [fl_compensativo]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[e1_tur_ordini_giorno] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_e1_tur_ordini_giorno_fl_confermato]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [fl_confermato]
GO
```

**EDIT 2**
I'm adding two example queries:

1 - This **big** SELECT caused the lock of the table in question and his wait type was PAGEIOLATCH_SH:
n.b: this is the query as it is executed by hibernate after evaluating the hbm mapping with several formulas inside.

```
select distinct ordinegior0_.id as id128_0_, giornooper1_.id as id510_1_, turnolite2_.id as id512_2_, dipendente3_.id as id396_3_, reparto4_.id as id468_4_, 
orarioserv5_.id as id521_5_, giornosett6_.id as id6_6_, periodoser7_.id as id519_7_, servizioop8_.id as id156_8_, ordinegior0_.riga as riga128_0_, 
ordinegior0_.n_ore as n2_128_0_, ordinegior0_.hh_inizio as hh7_128_0_, ordinegior0_.hh_fine as hh8_128_0_, ordinegior0_.overload as overload128_0_, 
ordinegior0_.dt_ordine_giorno as dt3_128_0_, ordinegior0_.dt_paghe as dt14_128_0_, ordinegior0_.nota as nota128_0_, ordinegior0_.fk_e1_tur_servizio as fk15_128_0_, 
ordinegior0_.fl_confermato as fl16_128_0_, ordinegior0_.dt_inserimento as dt17_128_0_, ordinegior0_.dt_modifica as dt13_128_0_, ordinegior0_.fl_bloccato as fl18_128_0_, 
ordinegior0_.fl_temporaneo as fl19_128_0_, ordinegior0_.fl_annullato as fl4_128_0_, ordinegior0_.tipo_riga as tipo20_128_0_, ordinegior0_.tipo_modifica as tipo33_128_0_, 
ordinegior0_.hh_ordinarie as hh22_128_0_, ordinegior0_.fl_compensativo as fl23_128_0_, ordinegior0_.descrizione as descrizi9_128_0_, 
ordinegior0_.fl_recupero as fl24_128_0_, ordinegior0_.fk_e0_segmento_dip as fk25_128_0_, ordinegior0_.fk_e1_tur_pian_reperibilita as fk26_128_0_, 
ordinegior0_.fk_e0_utente_inserimento as fk27_128_0_, ordinegior0_.fk_e0_utente_modifica as fk28_128_0_, 
ordinegior0_.fk_e0_prof_nodo as fk6_128_0_, ordinegior0_.fk_e1_tur_testata as fk29_128_0_, ordinegior0_.fk_e0_turno as fk30_128_0_, 
ordinegior0_.fk_e2_per_dipendente as fk5_128_0_, ordinegior0_.fk_parent_ordine_giorno as fk34_128_0_, ordinegior0_.fk_e1_tur_orario_servizio as fk12_128_0_, 
ordinegior0_.fk_e0_tipo_rischio as fk31_128_0_, ordinegior0_.fk_e0_gg_operativo as fk32_128_0_, 

(SELECT CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT 'x' FROM e1_tur_ordini_giorno_pubb p WHERE p.fk_e1_tur_ordine_giorno = ordinegior0_.id  
    AND p.fk_e2_per_dipendente=ordinegior0_.fk_e2_per_dipendente               
    AND p.hh_inizio = ordinegior0_.hh_inizio               
    AND p.hh_fine = ordinegior0_.hh_fine               
    AND p.fl_annullato=0) THEN 0           
                          ELSE 
    CASE WHEN (SELECT p.dt_lettura FROM e1_tur_ordini_giorno_pubb p WHERE p.fk_e1_tur_ordine_giorno = ordinegior0_.id 
                AND p.fk_e2_per_dipendente=ordinegior0_.fk_e2_per_dipendente               
                AND p.hh_inizio = ordinegior0_.hh_inizio               
                AND p.hh_fine = ordinegior0_.hh_fine               
                AND p.fl_annullato=0 ) IS NOT NULL               
                THEN 2 
                ELSE 1               
                END           END      ) as formula956_0_, 

(SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT count(ia.id)              FROM e1_tur_ind_agg_odg ia              
WHERE ia.fk_e1_tur_odg = ordinegior0_.id              AND ia.fl_manuale = 1) > 0           
THEN 1           ELSE 0       END) as formula957_0_, 

(SELECT CASE           WHEN ordinegior0_.fl_temporaneo = 1          THEN           
(SELECT COUNT(st.id)           FROM e1_tur_servizi_temporanei st          
 WHERE st.fk_e1_ordine_giorno = ordinegior0_.id           
 AND st.fk_e2_com_prestazione IS NOT NULL)        ELSE 0       END) as formula958_0_, 

 ( SELECT MIN(t.data_timbratura)        
 FROM e2_per_timbrature_odg ot JOIN e1_tur_timbrature t ON t.id = ot.fk_e1_tur_timbratura       
 WHERE ot.fk_e1_tur_ordine_giorno = ordinegior0_.id        AND t.fl_entrata = 1 ) as formula959_0_, 

 ( SELECT MIN(t.data_timbratura)        FROM e2_per_timbrature_odg ot JOIN e1_tur_timbrature t ON t.id = ot.fk_e1_tur_timbratura        
 WHERE ot.fk_e1_tur_ordine_giorno = ordinegior0_.id        AND t.fl_entrata = 0 ) as formula960_0_, 

giornooper1_.codice as codice510_1_, giornooper1_.descrizione as descrizi3_510_1_, giornooper1_.fl_lavorato as fl4_510_1_, giornooper1_.fl_riposo as fl5_510_1_, 
giornooper1_.fl_permesso as fl6_510_1_, giornooper1_.fl_rip_semplice as fl7_510_1_, giornooper1_.fl_reperibile as fl8_510_1_, 
giornooper1_.priorita_assegnazione as priorita9_510_1_, turnolite2_.codice as codice512_2_, turnolite2_.descrizione as descrizi3_512_2_, 
turnolite2_.hh_inizio as hh4_512_2_, turnolite2_.hh_fine as hh5_512_2_, turnolite2_.fl_attivo as fl6_512_2_, turnolite2_.codice_vis as codice7_512_2_, 
turnolite2_.fk_e0_tipo_turno as fk8_512_2_, dipendente3_.nome as nome396_3_, dipendente3_.cognome as cognome396_3_, dipendente3_.fl_sesso as fl4_396_3_, 
dipendente3_.alias as alias396_3_, dipendente3_.matricola as matricola396_3_, dipendente3_.fl_tracciato as fl7_396_3_, dipendente3_.fl_paghe as fl8_396_3_, 
dipendente3_.fl_outsourcing as fl9_396_3_, dipendente3_.fl_giostra as fl10_396_3_, dipendente3_.fl_segmento_est as fl11_396_3_, dipendente3_.gg_prova as gg12_396_3_, 
dipendente3_.codice_fiscale as codice13_396_3_, dipendente3_.dt_assunzione as dt14_396_3_, dipendente3_.dt_nascita as dt15_396_3_, 
dipendente3_.dt_licenziamento as dt16_396_3_, dipendente3_.num_badge as num17_396_3_, dipendente3_.codice_tracciato_paghe as codice18_396_3_, 
dipendente3_.costo_orario as costo19_396_3_, dipendente3_.fl_timbratura as fl20_396_3_, dipendente3_.dt_anzianita as dt21_396_3_, 
dipendente3_.numero_buono_pasto as numero22_396_3_, dipendente3_.fl_pref_da_recinto as fl32_396_3_, dipendente3_.fk_e2_hr_soggetto as fk34_396_3_, 
dipendente3_.fk_e0_utente_inserimento as fk23_396_3_, dipendente3_.fk_e0_utente_modifica as fk24_396_3_, dipendente3_.fk_e0_ccnl as fk25_396_3_, 
dipendente3_.fk_e0_unita_locale_nodo as fk26_396_3_, dipendente3_.dt_inserimento as dt27_396_3_, dipendente3_.dt_modifica as dt28_396_3_, 
dipendente3_.fk_e0_reparto as fk29_396_3_, dipendente3_.fk_e0_nodo_aziendale as fk30_396_3_, dipendente3_.fk_e0_prof_nodo as fk31_396_3_, 
reparto4_.codice as codice468_4_, reparto4_.descrizione as descrizi3_468_4_, reparto4_.dt_inserimento as dt4_468_4_, reparto4_.dt_modifica as dt5_468_4_, 
reparto4_.fk_e0_utente_inserimento as fk6_468_4_, reparto4_.fk_e0_utente_modifica as fk7_468_4_, reparto4_.fk_e0_prof_nodo as fk8_468_4_, 
orarioserv5_.codice as codice521_5_, orarioserv5_.hh_inizio as hh3_521_5_, orarioserv5_.hh_fine as hh4_521_5_, orarioserv5_.fl_dopo_mezzanotte as fl5_521_5_, 
orarioserv5_.dt_inserimento as dt6_521_5_, orarioserv5_.dt_modifica as dt7_521_5_, orarioserv5_.fk_e0_utente_inserimento as fk8_521_5_, 
orarioserv5_.fk_e0_utente_modifica as fk9_521_5_, orarioserv5_.fk_e0_prof_nodo as fk10_521_5_, orarioserv5_.fk_e0_giorno_settimana as fk11_521_5_, 
orarioserv5_.fk_e0_tipo_rischio as fk12_521_5_, orarioserv5_.fk_e1_tur_periodo_servizio as fk13_521_5_, orarioserv5_.fk_parent_orario_servizio as fk14_521_5_, 
giornosett6_.codice as codice6_6_, giornosett6_.giorno as giorno6_6_, periodoser7_.codice as codice519_7_, periodoser7_.dt_inizio as dt3_519_7_, 
periodoser7_.dt_fine as dt4_519_7_, periodoser7_.dt_inserimento as dt5_519_7_, periodoser7_.dt_modifica as dt6_519_7_, periodoser7_.fl_calendario as fl7_519_7_, 
periodoser7_.fl_festivo as fl8_519_7_, periodoser7_.fk_e0_utente_inserimento as fk9_519_7_, periodoser7_.fk_e0_utente_modifica as fk10_519_7_, 
periodoser7_.fk_e0_prof_nodo as fk11_519_7_, periodoser7_.fk_e1_tur_servizio as fk12_519_7_, servizioop8_.codice as codice156_8_, 
servizioop8_.descrizione as descrizi3_156_8_, servizioop8_.alias as alias156_8_, servizioop8_.fl_giostra as fl5_156_8_, servizioop8_.fl_fattura as fl6_156_8_, 
servizioop8_.fl_pattuglia as fl7_156_8_, servizioop8_.fl_temporaneo as fl8_156_8_, servizioop8_.fl_armato as fl9_156_8_, servizioop8_.fl_scacchiera as fl10_156_8_, 
servizioop8_.dt_scadenza as dt13_156_8_, servizioop8_.dt_inserimento as dt11_156_8_, servizioop8_.dt_modifica as dt12_156_8_, 
servizioop8_.codice_post_serv as codice14_156_8_, servizioop8_.codice_ps_cedente as codice15_156_8_, servizioop8_.cod_selettiva as cod16_156_8_, 
servizioop8_.ruolo_ext as ruolo17_156_8_, servizioop8_.fl_usa_selettiva as fl18_156_8_, servizioop8_.colore as colore156_8_, servizioop8_.fl_tolleranza as fl20_156_8_, 
servizioop8_.min_prima_fascia as min21_156_8_, servizioop8_.min_fasce_succ as min22_156_8_, servizioop8_.fl_badge_tag as fl23_156_8_, 
servizioop8_.fl_pausa as fl24_156_8_, servizioop8_.fl_pref_da_recinto as fl25_156_8_, servizioop8_.fk_e0_utente_inserimento as fk31_156_8_, 
servizioop8_.fk_e0_utente_modifica as fk32_156_8_, servizioop8_.fk_e0_prof_nodo as fk33_156_8_, servizioop8_.fk_e2_com_prestazione as fk30_156_8_, 
servizioop8_.fk_e0_servizio as fk29_156_8_ 


from e1_tur_ordini_giorno ordinegior0_ 
left outer join e0_conf_gg_operativi giornooper1_ 
on ordinegior0_.fk_e0_gg_operativo=giornooper1_.id 
left outer join e0_conf_turni turnolite2_ 
on ordinegior0_.fk_e0_turno=turnolite2_.id 
left outer join e2_per_dipendenti dipendente3_ 
on ordinegior0_.fk_e2_per_dipendente=dipendente3_.id 
left outer join e0_decod_reparti reparto4_ 
on dipendente3_.fk_e0_reparto=reparto4_.id 
left outer join e1_tur_orari_servizi orarioserv5_ 
on ordinegior0_.fk_e1_tur_orario_servizio=orarioserv5_.id 
left outer join e0_conf_giorni_settimana giornosett6_
 on orarioserv5_.fk_e0_giorno_settimana=giornosett6_.id 
left outer join e1_tur_periodi_servizi periodoser7_ 
 on orarioserv5_.fk_e1_tur_periodo_servizio=periodoser7_.id 
 left outer join e1_tur_servizi servizioop8_ 
 on periodoser7_.fk_e1_tur_servizio=servizioop8_.id 

 where ordinegior0_.dt_ordine_giorno>=@P0 
 and ordinegior0_.dt_ordine_giorno<=@P1 
 and (ordinegior0_.fk_e1_tur_orario_servizio in 
 (@P2 , @P3 , @P4 , @P5 , @P6 , @P7 , @P8 , @P9))
```

2 - This second SELECT query is way simpler and didn't cause any lock, but its execution time was worrying, 3-4 minutes.

```
    select distinct servizioop0_.id as id162, servizioop0_.codice as codice162, servizioop0_.descrizione as descrizi3_162_,
 servizioop0_.alias as alias162, servizioop0_.fl_giostra as fl5_162, servizioop0_.fl_fattura as fl6_162_, 
 servizioop0_.fl_pattuglia as fl7_162, servizioop0_.fl_temporaneo as fl8_162, servizioop0_.fl_armato as fl9_162_, 
 servizioop0_.fl_scacchiera as fl10_162, servizioop0_.dt_scadenza as dt13_162, servizioop0_.dt_inserimento as dt11_162_, 
 servizioop0_.dt_modifica as dt12_162, servizioop0_.codice_post_serv as codice14_162, 
 servizioop0_.codice_ps_cedente as codice15_162, servizioop0_.cod_selettiva as cod16_162, servizioop0_.ruolo_ext as ruolo17_162_, 
 servizioop0_.fl_usa_selettiva as fl18_162, servizioop0_.colore as colore162, servizioop0_.fl_tolleranza as fl20_162_, 
 servizioop0_.min_prima_fascia as min21_162, servizioop0_.min_fasce_succ as min22_162, servizioop0_.fl_badge_tag as fl23_162_, 
 servizioop0_.fl_pausa as fl24_162, servizioop0_.fl_pref_da_recinto as fl25_162, 
 servizioop0_.fk_e0_utente_inserimento as fk31_162, servizioop0_.fk_e0_utente_modifica as fk32_162, 
 servizioop0_.fk_e0_prof_nodo as fk33_162, servizioop0_.fk_e2_com_prestazione as fk30_162, 
 servizioop0_.fk_e0_servizio as fk29_162_ 

 from e1_tur_servizi servizioop0_ 
 where servizioop0_.fk_e0_prof_nodo in ('f4001621-6f70-11e1-94aa-    005056bb0003') 
 and 
 (exists (select 'EXTRA' from e1_tur_ordini_giorno ordinegior1_ 
   where ordinegior1_.fk_e1_tur_servizio=servizioop0_.id 
   and ordinegior1_.dt_ordine_giorno>='2015-06-01' 
   and ordinegior1_.dt_ordine_giorno<='2015-06-30'
   ))
```

The number of rows in e1_tur_ordini_giorno that are between  '2015-06-01' and   '2015-06-30' is likely 30.000 rows.
There are NO indexes on the table e1_tur_servizi.

Comment: Have you got any clusteted keys indexes on the table at all? and could you say that one of the querys that you are seeing is the problem if you use SQL Server Diagnostics Tracer tools, that it is doing an update or a select via this Clustered Key. Also have you Reindexed this Key on the Server?

Comment: In this table there is a clustered index (the unique GUID) and several non clustered indexes on some of the columns. I never used SQL server diagnostics tracer tool, I will try to understand how to use it (I have at least one query to analyze that I think can maybe be problematic). For the last point I remember that we have a procedure that rebuilds the indexes on that table every week.

Comment: Checkout this article to use the SQL Tracer tool to see what SQL is being used at the time, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms175047.aspx Without seeing the table structure you actually have its a bit hard for me to see where there could be some pitfalls, but i get the feeling the clustered index's are causing your Query Plan to get confused on what the best way the engine wants to perform your query, and this is locking the table, Maybe also showing us the Rogue query could help us to help you work out the problem

Comment: Thanks @RobbieTapping, I added the table structure for further help.
I will investigate in the use of the tracer also.

Comment: Does many of your queries inside NHibernate use the fk_Parent_ordine_giorno Foreign Key relationship by any chance? you got an example query which causes the lock.

Comment: Nope, the fk_Parent_ordine_giorno Foreign Key is rarely used, considering also that the field is rarely populated (so the many-to-one relationship inside the hbm.xml shouldn't be a worry). 

I' adding 2 queries that proved to be problematic: the first is the SELECT one that caused the lock, the other one, though not causing any lock had always a long execution time, in order of 3-4 minutes.

Comment: @RobbieTapping, sorry Robbie to bother you..I thought you may have missed my last comment and editing of the question since seems only you tried to help me. Thanks again